# Not getting property added through WFS

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I am trying to insert properties in shapefile using Openlayer and WFS layer. I wrote my code and I believe it is correct because in response I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:TransactionResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:UK_Postal="http://www.openplans.org/uk_portal" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:tiger="http://www.census.gov" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><wfs:TransactionSummary><wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted><wfs:totalUpdated>0</wfs:totalUpdated><wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted></wfs:TransactionSummary><wfs:TransactionResults/><wfs:InsertResults><wfs:Feature><ogc:FeatureId fid="new0"/></wfs:Feature></wfs:InsertResults></wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

As I am getting response you can check from complete stack

> wfs:totalInserted1</wfs:totalInserted>

But when I am reading back I am not getting the extra property that I have added. Here is my code:

```
var formatWFS2 = new ol.format.WFS();
    var pointGML = new ol.format.GML({
        featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/uk_portal',
        featureType: 'AB_post',
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
    });
    
    var pointWFS = function(p,f) {
        var node;
        switch(p) {
            case 'insert':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction([f],null,null,pointGML);
                break;
            case 'update':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,pointGML);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],pointGML);
                break;
        }
        
        //console.log(node);
        var payload = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
        console.log(payload);
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
                service: 'WFS',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                data: payload,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }, error: function(data) {
                    console.error(data);
                }
            }).done(function() {
                //sourceWFS.clear();
                console.log(" point features were posted to server");
            });
        
    }
```

This is the json which I am adding and writing properties here:

```
wfs.html:139 {"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":1,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"AB_post.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-233222.55760363,7790673.03403836],[-233223.96742674,7790673.41918759],[-233335.24515929,7790702.96970708],[-233301.26575108,7790777.5655439],[-233291.30310466,7790812.94485092],[-233217.13589042,7790756.28662714],[-233216.01896901,7790749.57981619],[-233211.98323025,7790748.84807779],[-233202.7519538,7790720.44402123],[-233196.2548373,7790706.68616474],[-233222.55760363,7790673.03403836]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"POSTCODE":"AB10 1AL","UPP":"00000000000000000003","PC_AREA":"AB","FERRETS":""}}],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}}
```

And this is how I am calling my  method:

```
var newFeature = new ol.Feature({
            'ferrets': 12
        })
        pointWFS('insert',newFeature);
```

This is my transanction XML

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Insert><AB_post xmlns="http://www.openplans.org/uk_portal"><FERRETS>12</FERRETS></AB_post></Insert></Transaction>
```

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Add also the generated Insert command. You can also copy that into the Demo request window of your GeoServer and try it directly. Shapefile format is kind of a toy format for GeoServer WFS and it is really suitable for testing only. I am remembering that GeoServer may well return "success" even if the transaction with shapefile fails. For reals needs use PostGIS.

Comment: Not sure if understood well but you can't add a new column using WFS-T. You can only add new records but if your original records does not contain already the column, when you will try to send a new data to WFS end point, it will append the data but not add any column and store it. If you don't retrieve WFS data with a column `ferrets` don't expect to be able to update/fill it: it does not exist.

Comment: @ThomasG77 I have added a new column in dbf file with name ''ferrerts'. My new json layer I have updated above but still I am not able to update/insert the data

Comment: @user30184 I have added my transaction command also

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new **Feature** with a single attribute called `ferrets` while your shapefile has an attribute called `FERRETS` so it will be dropped and a completely empty feature added to the shapefile. I'm not sure but I suspect that GeoServer doesn't bother to send null features back to the client.

If you want to add an attribute value to an existing feature then you must send that feature (with the new attribute set) to the server.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: select your feature, add the attribute and **update** it in WFS